# Calling an executable like a script

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking

I'm working on a HTTP/1.1 server in C as a learning experience and want to make it performant while still being dynamic. Performing a get or post on static files or scripts was easy enough, but I'd like to add the ability to call compiled binaries for greater speed.

Currently, I link these compiled binaries directly into the server binary, but I'd like to be able to update and hot swap them. I considered dynamically linking them as shared libraries, but I don't want to relink them to handle every request. I also considered creating a new process to run them, however that incurs significant overhead every request and makes getting the response back to the client difficult (I'm using OpenSSL sockets).

How could I efficiently relink these compiled binaries when they update, without shutting down the server?

I'm testing on Debian Sid and running on an AWS ECS instance with CentOS 7. Both have Linux kernel versions 4.19+

Comment: Uptime is overrated. I've found hot patching is not worth the obscure problems it causes on occasion. Patch and reboot.

Comment: Rebooting is entirely unnecessary. Restarting the webserver is not the same thing as rebooting. But Tyler is also probably entering the realm of premature optimisation. There are aspects of a webserver that become more performant under C, but large parts where it just doesn't matter. Or doesn't matter enough, or there are easier ways to get performance without sacrificing dev time. As a learning excersise, it's fine, but its practicality may be limited.

Comment: I told a classmate about this feature of the web server and he mentioned that the reloading of these compiled binaries sounds like reloading Apache modules, although they don't interact in the same way. Perhaps I could have a single config file which I'll tell my server to reload and the config file tells the web server which compiled binaries to include along with a version number, then it calls dlclose on the old binary and dlopen on the new one. From what I understand, this isn't too far off from what Apache does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to update and hot swap them. I considered dynamically linking them as shared libraries

You appear to believe that you can update a shared library (on disk) that a running server binary is currently using, and expect that running server process to start using the updated library.

That is *not* how shared libraries work. If you try that, your server process will either crash, or continue using the old library (depending on exactly how you update the library on disk).

This can be made to work in limited circumstances *if* you use `dlopen` to load the library, and if you can quiesce your server, and have it `dlclose` to unload the previously loaded version, and then `dlopen` updated version. But the exact details of making this work are quite tricky.

Comment: Right, I was suggesting that for every request, dlopen and dlclose would be called so that the next request after an update would always use the newer version. So what you are saying is that I should find someway to let the server know when the file has updated and it needs to reload the newer version. Makes sense, and sounds fun!